# How do you access data from a VCR cassette for testing?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, rubygems

I'm using the VCR gem and I've figured out how to record an API request to a cassette in JSON format. Now how do I access the information in the body of the response from that cassette?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to access the `raw_cassette_bytes` method which returns all the data from the VCR cassette:

```
VCR.use_cassette('path/to/cassette') do |cassette|
  puts cassette.send(:raw_cassette_bytes)
end
```

I have used this when trying to make sure that the ERB template for a VCR cassette looks correct and is generated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to offer an alternative that doesn't rely on calling a private method:

```rb
VCR.use_cassette('path/to/cassette') do |cassette|
  cassette.serializable_hash.dig("http_interactions", 0, "response", "body", "string")
end
```

The above will return a JSON string of the response body.